# Python: How to split a string column in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns one is `Date` and the other one is `Location(Object)` datatype, below is the format of Location columns with values :

```
 Date                                            Location
1     07/12/1912                            AtlantiCity, New Jersey   
2     08/06/1913                 Victoria, British Columbia, Canada   
3     09/09/1913                                 Over the North Sea   
4     10/17/1913                         Near Johannisthal, Germany   
5     03/05/1915                                    Tienen, Belgium   
6     09/03/1915                              Off Cuxhaven, Germany   
7     07/28/1916                              Near Jambol, Bulgeria   
8     09/24/1916                                Billericay, England   
9     10/01/1916                               Potters Bar, England   
10    11/21/1916                                     Mainz, Germany
```

my requirement is to split the Location by `","` separator and keep only the second part of it `(ex. New Jersey, Canada, Germany, England etc..)` in the Location column. I also have to check if its only a single element (values with single element having no ",")

Is there a way I can do it with predefined method without looping each and every row ?

Sorry if the question is off the standard as I am new to Python and still learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straight forward way is to `apply` the `split` method to each element of the column and pick up the last one:

```
df.Location.apply(lambda x: x.split(",")[-1])

1             New Jersey
2                 Canada
3     Over the North Sea
4                Germany
5                Belgium
6                Germany
7               Bulgeria
8                England
9                England
10               Germany
Name: Location, dtype: object
```

To check if each cell has only one element we can use `str.contains` method on the column:

```
df.Location.str.contains(",")

1      True
2      True
3     False
4      True
5      True
6      True
7      True
8      True
9      True
10     True
Name: Location, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

We could try with `str.extract`

```
print(df['Location'].str.extract(r'([^,]+$)'))    
#0            New Jersey
#1                Canada
#2    Over the North Sea
#3               Germany
#4              Belgium 
#5               Germany
#6              Bulgeria
#7               England
#8               England
#9               Germany
```